# Problemas con switch y case: label "n" not within a switch statement

Tags: c++

Actualmente me mandaron una asignación:

**Escribe un programa que muestre un mensaje que diga: teclear s para si, n para no; en caso de decir si: debe mostrar los numeros del 1 al 5 en caso de no: debe decir hasta luego.**

Estoy usando switch, no se si habrá algo mejor, por favor indicádmelo. y me da el error en el título con *case n*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    char c;
    cout << "Escribe una letra" << endl;
    cin >> c;
        switch (c)
        {case
            case 's':
                
                    int s = 0;
                    while (s<=5)
                    {
                        cout << s << endl;
                        s++;
            break;          
                    }
                        
        }   
            case 'n':
                
                    cout << "Hasta luego" << endl;

                
    
     
    return 0;
}
```

Si hay otro error pertinente, me falta algo o me dan consejos en general estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

En el código tienes tres errores dentro del switch:

**Dos case seguidos**

```
switch (c)
{case            // <<--- 1
    case 's':    // <<--- 2
```

Cada `case` debe indicar una condición seguida por dos puntos. el primer `case` sobra.

**Case sin break**

```
   case 's':
        int s = 0;
        while (s<=5)
        {
            cout << s << endl;
            s++;
            break; // Break del while (no del switch)
        }
                   // <<--- No hay break
```

Si no se usa `break` dentro de los `case` entonces el programa ejecutará varios `case` del tirón. Efectivamente, dentro de un `switch-case` la instrucción `switch` enruta el código a uno de los `case`, pero una vez realizado este salto, el código se ejecuta de forma lineal, esto quiere decir que una vez alcanzado el final de un `case` el código empezará a ejecutar el código correspondiente al siguiente `case`... siempre y cuando no se encuentre con un `break`.

A modo de ejemplo, el siguiente código imprimirá los `case` 1 y 2. El `case 0` no se ejecuta puesto que el `switch` salta directamente al `case 1` (y el `case 0` esta escrito **antes** que el `case 1`). El `case 3` no se ejecutará puesto que el `case 2` finaliza con un `break`:

```
int valor = 1;

switch( valor )
{
case 0:
  std::cout << "Este case no se ejecuta NUNCA\n";
case 1:
  std::cout << "Case 1\n";
case 2:
  std::cout << "Case 2\n";
  break;
case 3:
  std::cout << "Este case no se ejecuta NUNCA\n";
  break;
}
```

**Case fuera del ámbito del switch**

Fíjate que el `case 'n'` está fuera del ámbito del switch:

```
switch (c)
{ // <<--- inicio ámbito del switch
    case 's':
        
            int s = 0;
            while (s<=5)
            {
                cout << s << endl;
                s++;
    break;          
            }
                
} // <<--- fin del ámbito del switch
    case 'n': // Case fuera de su sitio
        
            cout << "Hasta luego" << endl;
```

Los `case` únicamente pueden emplearse dentro de un `switch`, luego tiene todo el sentido del mundo que el compilador se queje ya que este `case` está mal colocado.

Además, es un buen hábito que te acostumbres a usar un `break` en cada `case`. Así evitas que el programa ejecute varios `case` por error.

**Solución**

El programa, una vez corregido, (y bien tabulado) queda así:

```
char c;
cout << "Escribe una letra" << endl;
cin >> c;
switch (c)
{
case 's':
    int s = 0;
    while (s<=5)
    {
        cout << s << endl;
        s++;
        break;          
    }
    break;  

case 'n':
    cout << "Hasta luego" << endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus correcciones y tus increíbles explicaciones, me ayuda mucho esto. Sin duda no había notado que había puesto un case de más y no sabía que todos los case entraban en el switch. Muy útil.